# what does a type without a declaration mean?

Tags: ocaml

In OCaml, what does the following code really does?

```ml
module T = struct
  type t
end
```

It seems like there is no way to construct such a type `t` as it is not fully defined, yet it does compile.

I think one use of this is for FFI, where `t` is linked to something else at compile time, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This defines an abstract type. There is no reason for this definition to not compile. The fact that such definition

```ml
type t
```

does not give the user any way to create or use a value of type `t`
(without using externals) compared to the more standard

```ml
module M: sig
  type t
  val create: unit -> t
  val consume: t -> unit
end = struct
  ...
end
```

is a concern for the module writer, not the compiler.
Moreover, this kind of abstract type can be useful when writing binding:

```ml
type t
external create: unit -> t = "c_binding_to_create"
```

or as type-level tag in a phantom type

```ml
type meter
type second
module Unit : sig
  type 'a t
  val m: meter t
  val s: second t
  val ( * ): 'a t -> 'b t -> ('a*'b) t
  val ( + ): 'a t -> 'a t -> 'a t
end = struct
  type 'a t = float
  let m = 1.
  let s = 1.
  let ( * ) = ( *. )
  let ( + ) = ( +. )
end
```

Beware however that for such use case, the typechecker cannot prove inequality between abstract types which makes them unsuitable combined with GADTs and it is probably better to define the type above as

```ml
type meter = private Meter_tag
type second = private Second_tag
```

which makes it possible to write

```ml
type ('a,'b) eq = Refl: ('a,'a) eq
let absurd (x: (meter,second) eq) = match x with _ -> .
```